# ¿Como suma números de archivos de texto?

Tags: java

Que tal comunidad tengo el siguiente problema tengo un archivo de texto .txt en este archivo tengo un  nombre: producto, y su precio
 lo que sucede es que tengo que sumar el precio de cada producto  intente hacer lo siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi archivo de texto es el siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Declara `num` y `suma` de tipo `Int` y prueba..

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y el codigo debe ir siempre como texto, no como imagenes. Lee [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324)